# Ready columns Numpy/Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to read 3 columns using `numpy.loadtext` but I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with sequence.
```

A sample of the data:

```
0.5     0   -22
0.5     0   -21
0.5     0   -22
0.5     0   -21
```

**Column 1** is a distance that increases from 0.5 to 6.5 with 15 data samples at each distance.

**Column 2** is an angle, which increases 45deg every time distance returns to 0.5.

**Column 3** contains the data being measured (an RSSI), which decreases from about -20 to -70.

I am using the following code to try and load the three columns into separate arrays:

```
import numpy as np

r, theta, RSSI, null = np.loadtxt("bot1.txt", unpack=True)
```

I will be averaging the sampled RSSI at each distance/angle combination and then I hope to plot the data as a `3D` polar plot. I haven't got this far yet though.

Any thoughts as to why the `np.loadtxt` isn't working?

Answer (score 5):

Beyond the fact that you are unpacking 3 columns into four variables, I don't see any problem. In fact, this works with my NumPy 1.6.2, with:

```
r, theta, RSSI = np.loadtxt("bot1.txt", unpack=True)  # 3 columns => 3 variables
```

It is also possible to do the same thing in pure Python, so as to see if something else causes the problem (like an error in the file):

```
import numpy

def loadtxt_unpack(file_name):
    '''
    Reads a file with exactly three numerical (real-valued) columns.
    Returns each column independently.  
    Lines with only spaces (or empty lines) are skipped.
    '''

    all_elmts = []

    with open(file_name) as input_file:
        for line in input_file:

            if line.isspace():  # Empty lines are skipped (there can be some at the end, etc.)
                continue

            try:
                values = map(float, line.split())
            except:
                print "Error at line:"
                print line
                raise

            assert len(values) == 3, "Wrong number of values in line: {}".format(line)

            all_elmts.append(values)

    return numpy.array(all_elmts).T

r, theta, RSSI = loadtxt_unpack('bot1.txt')
```

In case of problem with the file (if a non-empty line cannot be interpreted as three floats), the problematic line is printed and an exception is raised.

Comment: Ah, I had actually put the null value in to check and see was there possibly something after the rssi value that was causing something funny to happen. I think it may be an issue with the size of the file.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the file contains only three columns in each line, that represent real numbers? I added a test program in my answer that reports problems if there is a line that does not conform to your expectations.

Comment: PS: How big is your input file? I have read files with millions of lines, with `loadtxt()`, if I remember correctly; I would be surprised if the size of the file were an issue.